# selectCheckboxMenu scroll at the desired position

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have this selectCheckboxMenu with many items inside and updates each time I click it. The problem is, it returns its scrolling back to the top. What I want is when I click an item inside, it should stay at its current scrolling position so that I don't have to scroll it down again. How can I do it?

```
<h:form id="frmSumChart" >
 <p:overlayPanel id="pnlSearch" ..... >
  .....
  .....
  <h:panelGrid>
    <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="chkKey" value="#{sChart.key}" widgetVar="widKey" ..... >
      <f:selectItems value="#{sChart.keyList}" />
      <p:ajax listener="#{sChart.validate()}" update="chkKey" oncomplete="widKey.show()" />
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
  </h:panelGrid>
 </p:overlayPanel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: What is being done in `#{sChart.validate()}`? What is happening is that you're re-opening that menu everytime the user selects a value. If you want to prevent that behaviour, you'll need to execute that bean method in another moment (for example, `onHide` of the `selectCheckboxMenu`)

Comment: my listener allows my selectCheckboxMenu to prevent the user from selecting more than 10 items inside. that's what it do. when the total of items selected reach 10, other items will disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe your question fully, what you are trying to do in validate method. If you are not changing any state of the p:selectCheckboxMenu then no need of the update statement i believe.
  If you want only to show in a dialog what are selected then what u r doing oncomplete is correct. I believe everything is ok in your XHTML.